# Badge button in app iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios9, uibarbuttonitem, badge

I could really use some recomendations about what or how to have a badge button inside the app. I am currently uisng [BBBadgeBarButtonItem](https://github.com/TanguyAladenise/BBBadgeBarButtonItem), but it has a bug in iOS9 that the badge number is in a rectangle and not in a circle.

Like this:

[image]

So, I was wondering if anybody could help with other suggestions(pods or anything else) that work correctly even with iOS9. Doesn't matter if it is for `UIBarButton` or `UIButton`

Comment: Why don't you fix it its open source you can change it easily . I just saw the sample its woking in on iOS 9 .

Comment: What I was not sure was that if I fix it on my computer...when someone else makes a pod install won't they still have the bug? Or should I copy the git project on my account and fix it there and then use the project from my account(sorry if this sounds stupid) ...but anyway I think that Muhammad Nabeel Arif's answer solves my problem. Thanks!

Comment: It was up to you if you have fixed it for yourself only or also share with community .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of good open source badge controls are available out there. As given below:

- [DNFlyingBadge](https://github.com/normand1/DNFlyingBadge)
- [MIBadgeButton-Swift](https://github.com/mustafaibrahim989/MIBadgeButton-Swift)
- [M13BadgeView](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13BadgeView)
- [Sheriff](https://github.com/gemr/sheriff)

If you want to see more, lot of pods available at [cocoapods](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=badge) for Badge view in iOS.